# stringstream does not reset across several calls

Tags: c++, input, stringstream, istringstream

I'm trying to load in input from a file, representing students. Each student has a name and list of scores, like so:

```
Name John Wayne
Scores 100 90 80 100 0

Name Bob Dwight
Scores 0 0 10 100

Name Dummy Student
Scores 0 0
```

I am reading this through a class structure like so. A classroom object keeps a list of all students.

```
class Student
{
    string first_name;
    string last_name;
    vector<int> quizzes;

public:
    void read(istream & in){
        string line;

        // Name initialization
        getline(in, line);
        stringstream namereader(line);

        string word;
        namereader >> word; // Go past "Name"
        namereader >> word;
        first_name = word; // Second word in a line is firstname
        namereader >> word;
        last_name = word; // Third word in a line is lastname
        
        // Quizzes
        getline(in, line); // line after name contains quiz scores
        stringstream quizreader(line);
        quizreader >> word; // Go past "Quiz"
        int quizgrade;
        while(quizreader >> quizgrade){ // Read quiz scores and insert
            quizzes.insert(quizzes.end(), quizgrade);
        }

        // Putting quizreader.str(""), quizreader.clear() does not work

        //Empty Line between each student
        getline(in, line);
    }
    
    void print(ostream & out) const{
        out << "Name    " << first_name << " " << last_name << endl;
        out << "QZ Ave: " <<  endl;

        for (int i : quizzes){
            cout << i << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    friend ostream & operator <<(ostream &out, const Student & student){
        student.print(out);
        return out;
    }

    friend istream & operator >>(istream &in, Student & student){
        student.read(in);
        return in;
    }
};
```

Classroom:

```
class Classroom{
    vector<Student> students;
public:
    void print(ostream & out) const{
        for (Student s : students){
            out << s << endl;
        }
    }

    void read(istream & in){
        Student s;
        while (in >> s){
            students.insert(students.end(), s);
        }
    }

    friend ostream & operator <<(ostream &out, const Classroom & cl){
        cl.print(out);
        return out;
    }

    friend istream & operator >>(istream &in, Classroom & cl){
        cl.read(in);
        return in;
    }
};
```

Main function:

```
int main(){
    ifstream in("classroom.txt");
    Classroom cl;
    in >> cl;
    cout << cl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to print this out, I noticed that my stringstream does *not* reset across the calls done by the for loop in Classroom::read.

This means the output of the main function is:

```
John Wayne
Scores 100 90 80 100 0

Bob Dwight
Scores 100 90 80 100 0 0 0 10 100

Dummy Student
Scores 100 90 80 100 0 0 0 10 100 0 0
```

I have tried clear all of my stringstreams with .clear(), and .str(""). They don't work, regardless of where I place them in read(), and in which order. What is curious to me is that `quizreader` retains all of the previous numbers, but `namereader` keeps going on and takes the next name as expected. Is this a problem with opening multiple stringstreams? Improper initialization?

I am assuming all inputs are of the correct type, those problems I will be fixing later. I have read almost every post I could find on this site related to this topic, but I cannot seem to find a working solution.

Comment: I think you are complicating things. `istream` can extract tokens using `>>` operator, even newlines can be taken care of using the same.

Comment: You're reading into the same `Student` over and over without resetting its content between reads.  This has nothing to do with string streams. What happens when you plop `quizzes.clear();` before entering the quiz-reader loop?

Comment: @WhozCraig I guessed that at first, but when I called students.size() it returns the expected number of students, so I assumed that wasn't the problem. How should I rebuild the loop to properly construct a new student?

Comment: @KevinLi A quick fix is to call `quizzes.clear();` before reading quiz scores. That ensures the vector is empty before reading new values.

Answer (score 1):

In your `Classroom::read` member function you construct a `Student` object that is reused to read each student record:

```
void read(istream & in){
    Student s;
    while (in >> s){
        students.insert(students.end(), s);
    }
}
```

The problem is that in the `Student::read` function you reuse the `vector<int> quizzes;` member for each student but you never `.clear()` or empty it between students. You keep appending quiz scores. That explains your output.

A quick fix, with minimal changes to what you've written, is to call `quizzes.clear();` before reading quiz scores. That ensures the vector is empty before reading new values.

Note: When adding a value to the end of a `std::vector`, instead of doing `students.insert(students.end(), s);` you can just say `students.push_back(s);`.

Comment: How should I fix this? Wouldn't clear() remove all the data that I need to calculate things?

Comment: @KevinLi When you add the `Student` to the vector you are adding a **copy** to the container. That data is fine. You just need to "reset" the temporary `Student` object you reuse in the input loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are unnecessarily complicating things by using `std::stringstream`, `std::istream` and `std::getline`. You can simply use `std::istream` without using anything else. Only you have to do additional state management.

As for retained values in `quizzes`, you can change your reading logic a bit in `Classroom::read()`.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// Name ... Scores ... Name ... Scores ...
class Student
{
    string first_name;
    string last_name;
    vector<int> quizzes;
public:
    friend istream & operator >>(istream &in, Student & student){
        student.read(in);
        return in;
    }

    void read(istream& in)
    {
        string token;
        int state = 0;  // 0 - name, 1 - scores
        int name_cnt = 0;
        
        while (in >> token)
        {
            if (token.empty())
                continue;
                
            
            if (state == 1 && token == "Name")
            {
                break;
            }
            
            // cout << token << '\n';
            if (token == "Name")
            {
                state = 0;
                continue;
            }
            else if (token == "Scores")
            {
                name_cnt = 0;
                state = 1;
                continue;
            }
            
            if (state == 0)
            {
                if (name_cnt == 0)
                    first_name = token;
                else
                    last_name = token;
                name_cnt++;
            }
            else if (state == 1)
            {
                quizzes.push_back(std::stoi(token));
            }
        }
        cout << first_name << ' ' << last_name << '\n';
        for (auto x : quizzes) cout << x << ' '; cout << '\n';
    }
};


class Classroom
{
public:
    void read(istream & in){
        while (true)
        {
            Student s;
            if (in >> s)
                students.push_back(s);
            else
                break;
        }
    }
private:
    friend istream & operator >>(istream &in, Classroom & cl){
        cl.read(in);
        return in;
    }
    
    vector<Student> students;
};
int main()
{
    ifstream in("sample.txt");
    if (!in.is_open())
    {
        return 1;
    }
    Classroom C;
    C.read(in);
    return 0;
}
```